# Php - Display page content from multiple tables?

Tags: php, mysql, sql, html

My contents of website are display from a datatable (ex. ContentTable) with Ajax. There are 5 pages.
My problem is that, I would like to use another table, but ONLY on page 3.
For example:

**ContentTable:**

```
pageid | header       | content       |...
  1    |  "Welcome"   | "Main Page"   |...
  3    |     AnotherTable(fruits)     |...
```

*Table2*

```
id | type      | description
1  | fruit     | "In botany, a fruit is the...."
2  | vegetable | "Vegetables are parts of...."
```

**Table3**

```
id | type | name | description
1  | fruit| apple| "An apple is a sweet...."
...
```

In this case I would like to display fruit/apple on page 3.

#### Example for the SQL:

I get the current page like:
`$GetPageID = isset($_GET['pg']);`

The basic sql is like:
`SELECT header, content FROM ContentTable WHERE pageid=$GetPageID`

```
/* run extra SQL query */
if ($GetPageID == 3){
$SQL = "SELECT type, description From Table2;"
$result = mysqli_query($conn, $sql);
if (mysqli_num_rows($result) > 0) {
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result)) {
        echo 'Type: '.$row["type"].'<br>Description: '.$row["description"].'<br><a href="...">Show more about'.$row["type"].'</a>';
    }
} else {
    echo "the table is empty";
}
}
```

But I would like to use just a single query.

Comment: We can't see your coding attempt.  Your question is currently Too Broad.

Comment: You must provide an example that can be used to reproduce your error. Please update your question accordingly.

Comment: @Adam Chubbuck Hey! I have no error. I haven’t any idea, how to make it work.